# C# SQL Dependency detecting own call

Tags: c#, sqldependency

I have a form managing data from database's table.
I created a SQL Dependency and it works fine.
When I want to change something `OnDependencyChange` event fires and reminds me that data has been changed.
Do you know how to detect and don't fire the `OnDependencyChange` event when I change data in form myself, not by another user with running application on another PC.

Comment: Do you have any sort of login page/authentication mechanism?

Comment: Yes, i have access to user's data all the time

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid your testing showing up in your logs, you can utilize pre-processor directives such as

```
#if !DEBUG
    //perform change tracking
#endif
```

Or you can use

```
if(!Debugger.IsAttached) //change tracking
```

Alternately, you'll need to create a black list of computer names that don't utilize change tracking and compare the caller computer name with `Environment.MachineName`